# switches with circuiTikZ produce compile errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, circuitikz

I tried to compile an example from the circuiTikZ Manual which includes a switch.
However, the compiler stopped with an error message.

Can anybody help?

I use an iMac with macOS 11.0.1 Big Sur.
My Latex installation is done with TexLive and I have the newest release 2020.
The circuitikz directories are installed at the following path:

/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz

The example is taken from the circuiTikZ Manual version 1.2.5 (2020/10/14) October 14, 2020,
page 104.

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{standalone}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
  \draw(0,0) node[spdt] (Sw) {}
  (Sw.in) node[left] {in}
  (Sw.out 1) node[right] {out 1}
  (Sw.out 2) node[right] {out 2};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The compiler stops with the following error message:

[image]

In the log file I found the following message:

! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `compatibility' for package` circuitikz'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...

l.391

?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.391

The option `compatibility' was not declared in package` circuitikz', perhaps yo
u
misspelled its name. Try typing  <return>  to proceed.

Comment: There is no problem with version 1.2.3 of circuitikz. Is your version up to date?

Comment: The circutikz.sty file contains the header lines: \def\pgfcircversion{1.2.5}
\def\pgfcircversiondate{2020/10/14}. So it seems to be up to date. However the line before says: \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}. The first line in the log file is:This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020). May this be a problem LaTeX2e via pdfTeX?

Comment: Problem solved. I had an old distribution installed in my private texmf  path.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was related to a local stale file